# How to save data attributes in database?

Tags: python, jquery, json

I'm implementing a website and I need to save in database some variables that comes from HTML. The idea is save the paragraphs of the text that the user marked and save on database to show it when the user access the page (like in *medium.com*).

When the user click on paragraph I can't refresh the page, I just need to save on database the paragraph id (`data-artigo`) that was clicked.

That's my view `details.html` and I need to save in the database the values `artigo.pk` and `lei.pk`

```
   <!-- Begin Post Content -->
     <div class="article-post">
       {% for artigo in artigos %}   
         <p class='artigo'  data-artigo = "{{artigo.pk}}" data-lei = "{{lei.pk}}">
            {{artigo}}
         </p>
       {% endfor %}
      </div>
   <!-- End Post Content -->
```

I have a js function that receive those values and set a yellow background (`.highlight`) to mark the paragraph that was clicked. So I have to save those data in database:

```
$("p.artigo").on("dblclick",(function(e){
    let artigo = $(this).data('artigo');
    let lei = $(this).data('lei');
    let is_marked;

    if ($(this).hasClass( "highlight" )){
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        is_marked = false;
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        is_marked = true;
    }        
}));
```

That is the table (my model) when I need to store those data:

```
class Marcacao(models.Model):
    lei = models.ForeignKey(Lei, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Lei', related_name='marcacaoArtigos')
    artigo = models.ForeignKey(Lei, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Artigo', related_name='marcacaoLei')
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='marcacaoUsuário', related_name='marcacaoUsuario')

    is_marked = models.BooleanField('Está Marcado?', blank=True, default=False)
    description = models.TextField('Descrição', blank = True, null=True)
```

If I'm not wrong, I think that I need to create a function in the view and pass those data as parameter to this function, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet with this depends on how you want this to work.
If the user clicking a paragraph is considered a 'submit' perhaps run an Ajax query from the JS to the view and POST the data back to be put into the model.
However if you want to continue activity on the page consider using Django Rest Framework and creating an API call you can again send off data in an Ajax query to.
My suggestion would be DRF, it's pretty simple to serialize data and save into the model.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

You register your api in urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
api_patterns = [
    router.register(r'selected-paragraph', api.selectedParagraphViewSet)
]
urlpatterns = [
url(r'api/', include(api_patterns)),
```

Then in your api.py:

```
class selectedParagraphViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewset):
    queryset = Marcacao.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarcacaoSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            data = {
                'lei': request.data.pop('lei'),
                'artigo': request.data.pop('artigo'),
                'is_marked': request.data.pop('is_marked'),
                'usuario': request.user
            }
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data, method='post')
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except serializers.ValidationError:
            print(traceback.print_exc())
            raise
```

Then in your serializers.py:

```
class MarcacaoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def Meta:
        model = Marcacao
        fields = '__ALL__'
```

And finally a nice ajax call to send it all off:

```
var submitData = {
    'let': lei,
    'artigo': artigo,
    'is_marked': is_marked
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/selected-paragraph',
    method: 'PUT',
    data: submitData,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
     },
     success: function(data, stat, xhr) {
         console.log("Was a success");
     },
     failure: function(xhr, stat, err){
         console.log('POST error');
         console.log((xhr.responseJSON && xhr.responseJSON.msg) ? xhr.responseJSON.msg : '"'+err+'" response when communicating with server.');
      }
});
```

Also good to note is you can eliminate even the need for the create function in api.py if you can pass the request.user in the Ajax call, but I figured this way would show better how the data is input into the database.

Comment: tku so much. I got some ideas based on your code and I solved my problem. But asap I'm gonna implement exactly as you said. It's a more ellegant way.